# How to read multiple text files in Spark for document clustering?

Tags: java, apache-spark, machine-learning, nlp, hierarchical-clustering

I want to read multiple text documents from a directory for document clustering.
For that, I want to read data as:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster("local[*]").set("spark.executor.memory", "2g");
JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate();
Dataset<Row> dataset = spark.read().textFile("path to directory");
```

Here, I don't want to use
    JavaPairRDD data = context.wholeTextFiles(path);
     because I want Dataset as a return type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In scala you could write this:

```
context.wholeTextFiles("...").toDS()
```

In java you need to use an Encoder. See [the javadoc for more detail](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Encoder.html).

```
JavaPairRDD<String, String> rdd = context.wholeTextFiles("hdfs:///tmp/test_read");
Encoder<Tuple2<String, String>> encoder = Encoders.tuple(Encoders.STRING(), Encoders.STRING());
spark.createDataset(rdd.rdd(), encoder).show();
```